# I have an nodejs app, is this post a hacker attack?

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have a node js app behind a nginx proxy server.
I have seen some calls as:

```
[30/Aug/2020:05:42:11 GMT-0300] "POST /api/jsonws/invoke" 404 136 - 2.591 ms
```

What is this? Is it a hacker attack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a common endpoint for [JSON-WSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-WSP), so yes, it's a bot looking for an inning. If you are not running JSON web services, which you'd know if you were, then you can almost certainly ignore it.